# Laravel Eloquent multiple wheres gives wrong results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Why this code below is returning wrong results?

```
        $player->wins = Game::where('home_player_1', '=', $player->id)
                            ->orWhere('home_player_2', '=', $player->id)
                            ->orWhere('home_player_3', '=', $player->id)
                            ->orWhere('home_player_4', '=', $player->id)
                            ->where('result', '=','1') // 1 = win
                            ->get();

        $player->losses = Game::where('home_player_1', '=', $player->id)
                            ->orWhere('home_player_2', '=', $player->id)
                            ->orWhere('home_player_3', '=', $player->id)
                            ->orWhere('home_player_4', '=', $player->id)
                            ->where('result', '=','0') // 0 = lose
                            ->get();

        $player->matches = Game::where('home_player_1', '=', $player->id)
                            ->orWhere('home_player_2', '=', $player->id)
                            ->orWhere('home_player_3', '=', $player->id)
                            ->orWhere('home_player_4', '=', $player->id)
                            ->get();
```

What i get is like 5matches / 5 wins / 5losses when in real its 5/5/0. How should i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `home_player_x` clauses into a **nested** where condition clause:

```php
$player->wins = Game::where(function ($query) use ($player) {
  return $query->where('home_player_1', $player->id)
  ->orWhere('home_player_2', $player->id)
  ->orWhere('home_player_3', $player->id)
  ->orWhere('home_player_4', $player->id);
})->where('result', 1)
->get();

...
```

This way, it doesn't conflict with that last `->where('result')` clause.

Additionally, since you're reusing this clause multiple times, define it as a variable, and reuse it:

```php
$conditional = function ($query) use ($player) {
  return $query->where(function ($subQuery) use ($player) {
    return $subQuery->orWhere('home_player_1', $player->id)
    ->orWhere('home_player_2', $player->id)
    ->orWhere('home_player_3', $player->id)
    ->orWhere('home_player_4', $player->id);
  })
});

$player->wins = Game::where($conditional)->where('result', 1)->get();
$player->losses = Game::where($conditional)->where('result', 0)->get();
$player->matches = Game::where($conditional)->get();
```

Or, consider defining this as a Scope on the `Game` model, so you can call `Game::playerMatches($player)->where('result', 1)->get()`, etc. See the Documentation for that:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes

I won't really touch too much on this, but defining numbered columns, like `home_player_1`, `home_player_2`, etc. is generally considered bad data practice. You should define a `home_players` table, or `games_players`, with a `type` column for `home` or `away` table and associate `Game` and `Players` that way.

Comment: Thanks, i will change my db structure anyway, as u mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the post on [Logical Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping) in the Laravel Docs. I think based on that, your statement for `matches` should be:

```
$player->matches = Game::where(function ($query) use ($player) {
    $query->where('home_player_1', '=', $player->id)
          ->orWhere('home_player_2', '=', $player->id)
          ->orWhere('home_player_3', '=', $player->id)
          ->orWhere('home_player_4', '=', $player->id);
})->get();
```

I am not sure if this helps as I do not have the rest of the code, but please test it and let me know.

Also from the docs:
`"In fact, you should generally always group calls to the orWhere method in parentheses in order to avoid unexpected query behavior."`

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Need to modify the orWhere() condition, Instead of above you can use below where clause:

```
$player->wins = Game::where('result', '=','1') // 1 = win
    ->where(function ($query) use ($player) {
        $query->where('home_player_1', '=', $player->id)
            ->orWhere('home_player_2', '=', $player->id)
            ->orWhere('home_player_3', '=', $player->id)
            ->orWhere('home_player_4', '=', $player->id);
    })->get();

$player->losses = Game::where('result', '=', '0') // 0 = lose
    ->where(function ($query) use ($player) {
        $query->where('home_player_1', '=', $player->id)
            ->orWhere('home_player_2', '=', $player->id)
            ->orWhere('home_player_3', '=', $player->id)
            ->orWhere('home_player_4', '=', $player->id);
    })->get();


$player->matches = Game::
    where(function ($query) use ($player) {
        $query->where('home_player_1', '=', $player->id)
            ->orWhere('home_player_2', '=', $player->id)
            ->orWhere('home_player_3', '=', $player->id)
            ->orWhere('home_player_4', '=', $player->id);
    })->get();
```

When there were multiple orWhere() then normal conditions do not work, Need to add them under a single where.